# Run ./configure in a bash and redirect out/err to a file

Tags: c, bash, shell, redirect, compilation

I need to run ./configure in a bash and redirect out/err to a file, but I got 2 issue :

1) using something like :

```
ARG_COOKIES="--enable-cookies"
ARG_ENABLEFILE="--enable-file"
cmd=configure
"./$cmd" "$ARG_COOKIES" "ARG_ENABLEFILE" > logfile.conf 2>&1
```

I'm not able to see the result of configure in runtime..

2) I'm getting :

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/SRC/zabbix-4.2.6':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

Could someone help me understand?
THX!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see results on the screen and keep them in the file too you need to do the following:

```
"./$cmd" "$ARG_COOKIES" "ARG_ENABLEFILE" 2>&1 | tee logfile.conf
```

For the second check if there is `config.log` being created and see what is inside. Possible it is something with missing libs or incorrect LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I've tried your suggestion but the output of ./configure command was only in logfile.conf , nothing is printed on the screen. This ./configure command is launched inside a bash script just to clarify my case.

Comment: It should output to screen regardless if it is standalone or inside another script. For test you can try replacing cmd from configure to simple script that will just echo some text. You should see it on the screen. Second thing is you probably forgot to add $ to `ARG_ENABLEFILE` in second argument - should be `"$ARG_ENABLEFILE"`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions : regarding $ARG_ENABLEFILE var sorry, it was a typo! :) Unfortunately I still have issue in compiling using my shell script : it's like ./compile does not receipt LD_LIBRARY_PATH even if is present as export in my shell script (it's confirmed by the $(env) output.